# Filter list to remove similar, but not identical, entries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list containing several thousand names that are all unique strings, but I would like to filter them to produce a shorter list so that if there are similar names only one is retained. For example, the original list could contain:

Mickey Mouse

Mickey M Mouse

Mickey M. Mouse

The new list would contain just one of them - it doesn't really matter which at this moment in time. It's possible to get a similarity score using the code below (where *a* and *b* are the text being compared), so providing I pick an appropriate ratio it I have a way of making a include/exclude decision.

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

What I'm struggling to work out is how to populate the second list from the first one. I'm sure it's a trivial matter, but it baffling my newbie brain.

I'd have thought something along the lines of this would have worked, but nothing ends up being populated in the second list.

```
for p in ppl1:
    for pp in ppl2:
       if difflib.SequenceMater(None, p, pp).ratio() <=0.9:
           ppl2.append(p)
```

In fact, even if that did populate the list, it'd still be wrong. I guess it'd need to compare the name from the first list to all the names in the second list, keep track of the highest ratio scored, and then only add it if the highest ratio was less that the cutoff criteria.

Any guidance gratefully received!

Comment: What's in `ppl1`, and what's in `ppl2`?

Comment: ppl1 is the list containing the original names, ppl2 being the new list containing the filtered names. As you iterate through ppl1 you'd end up adding names to ppl2, against which you'd be comparing further names from ppl1. Or at least that was the approach i was thinking of.

Comment: So initially `ppl2` is empty? In that case, your inner loop is never going to do any work.

Comment: Btw., this is not a trivial problem. IIUC, what you're trying to do is [agglomerative clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) and there are a few choices to make to get an effective algorithm for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to risk never getting an accept because this may be too advanced for you, but here's the optimal solution.

What you're trying to do is a variant of [agglomerative clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering). A [union-find algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) can be used to solve this efficiently. From all pairs of distinct strings `a` and `b`, which can be generated using

```
def pairs(l):
    for i, a in enumerate(l):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
            yield (a, l[j])
```

you filter the pairs that have a similarity ratio `<= .9`:

```
similar = ((a, b) for a, b in pairs
                  if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, p, pp).ratio() <= .9)
```

then union those in a [disjoint-set forest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9488284/166749). After that, you loop over the sets to get their representatives.

Comment: You're right, way beyond my level of comprehension. But I've sure others with more brains that I will find it useful,.

Comment: @megadyptes There was a Coursera course on algorithms by Sedgewick that treated union-find algorithms right in the first week -- you may be able to find the videos somewhere. The explanation was quite lucid.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it.

One strategy would be to go through all pairs of names and, if a certain pair is too similar to each other, only keep one, and then iterate this until no two pairs are too similar. Of course, the result would now depend on the initial order of the list, but if your data is sufficiently clustered and your similarity score metric sufficiently nice, it should produce what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this pair-comparison approach, perhaps using the Mickey Mouse example originally posted,and perhaps including a Donald Duck as an entry that should be distinct? If i understand what you're saying, the ppl2 list is redundant as you'd be removing matching names from within ppl1?

Comment: There's no need for an expensive iterative algorithm, see my answer. There's also no need for anything to depend on the order of the input, since you can take the shorter of two strings when deciding which one to keep (and back off to the `min` when they're of equal length).

Comment: @larsmans our algorithms both need to enumerate all pairs of words, hence they have the same complexity. This is also the best you can do without more information about the structure of the similarity metric.

Comment: @zodiac: but you'd need to iterate multiple times over all pairs. My solution takes O(n² α(n²)) where α(n) << lg lg n; I only need to see each pair once.

Comment: Yes, I see that you are right. I had thought to keep track of already-seen pairs but I realize this would need O(n^2) space.